# Printing a double without the decimal places

Tags: c

I have a number stored as a `double` and want to print it without the decimal places.  So if I had the double value `919545634521.000000`, it is always printed with the decimal places added to it.  How can I print it without it so it looks like: `919545634521`?

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double number = 9220343120;
    printf("%??\n", number);
}
```

Comment: why a double and not integer?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove all the unnecessary parts and jumped straight to the point.  You want to print a double without the decimal places.  Too much?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try

```
printf("%.0lf\n",phoneNum);
```

you may also prefer

```
long long phoneNum;
phoneNum = strtoll(buffer,NULL,0);
printf("%lld\n",phoneNum);
```

instead. Depending on the system, though, you may need other function to convert (I think it's `_strtoui64` for windows).

Comment: The one component that all the other answers spitting out formats are missing... the `l`.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: The `l` is unnecessary: the `f` conversion specifier applies to `double` arguments, and the `l` length modifier has no effect on it.

Comment: @caf: Perhaps, but I always try to tell all students to get in the habit of using `f` for floats and `lf` for doubles, even if it strictly isn't necessary for doubles.  That way there is no confusion when using similar functions that does depend on this (i.e., `scanf()`).

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: I can see how that would help, but consider that there is also a valuable lesson in understanding *why* printf doesn't have a `float` format specifier.

Comment: caf, yes and I am grateful for it.

Answer (score 4):

Use %0.0lf or go with an integer

[Lookup format specs for printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Beware, `f` is not the proper format for a double-precision number... it's `lf`.

Comment: My bad, thanks Jeff, my late night brain cast his double to a float.

Comment: Both `%f` and `%lf` are the proper formats for `double` arguments.  It is *impossible* to pass a `float` argument to `printf`, they are always promoted to `double` in a variable argument list.

Answer (score 3):

Well, don't store the phone number as a floating-point number (one wrong move, and you'll end up with your telephone numbers getting **rounded** for you).

Store it as an integer or a string.

Comment: the requirement is to store it in a double...i mean this code snippet is part of a bigger program which deals with mobile numbers...!!! so the string buffer and teh doubles are used interchangeably...!!! thanx anyways !!!

Comment: Why would you store mobile numbers as doubles?  I wouldn't mind having 3.14159 or 6.0e23 as my phone number, but I don't think AT&T would go for it.  On most systems, a 64-bit unsigned integer has *more* significant digits than a double (double is typically 64 bits, but it "wastes" some of them on the exponent).

Comment: General rule if thumb: ask yourself "Does it have meaning if I add two of these together?" If the answer is no (ie, for a phone number), store it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

`printf ("%.0f\n", phoneNum);` should work.

Comment: yah, still would look into just doing an integer since you dont need the precision.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for *precision* - the format specifier `%.0f` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other compiler support, but GCC supports the 'g' format specifier, which will print a double using the least space required for full precision.  For example:

```
double d1 = 10.000;
double d2 = 25.03;
printf( "d1: %g\nd2: %g\n", d1, d2 );
```

will result in:

```
d1: 10
d2: 25.03
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use cpp you can indicate the precession of decimals with **'showpoint'**. showpoint is a flag for std stream cout, look at the example to see the behavior of showpoint. You can also read the more detailed documentation here [cpp reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpoint/?kw=showpoint)

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

// check out this example
for( double number : {34521.0010100, 1.0, 1.01, -1.0, -1.01, 0.0, 1.0e+10, -1.0001e-10 } )
     cout << "showpoint: " << showpoint << number << "  noshowpoint: " << noshowpoint << number << '\n' ;

}
```